# Date value out of bound exception in reactnative

Tags: reactjs, react-native, date, datetime, react-native-calendars

I am facing one problem that while using new Date in reactnative.

Here is the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedDate) {
      let date = new Date(selectedDate);
      let dateString = new Date(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
        .toISOString()
        .split("T")[0];

      console.log(dateString);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [selectedDate]);
```

My selectedDate is something like "04 nov 22" and with help of above procedure I am trying to get it convert to "2022-11-04". The strange part is that if I am running this code in chrome console and even in JSFiddle it's working fine but in reactnative its throwing me an error.

Is there anything to do in code to make it work with react native ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Managed to work with this :

```
moment("04 nov 2022", "DD MMM YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD")

output : "2022-11-04"
```